# Not sure how the limit of this function is 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I was working on this and I had to express this function as a maclaurin series and find the radius of convergence: $$f(x) = e^x + e^{2x}$$ I know what the maclaurin series is but I am having trouble getting the radius of convergence. Using the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), I need to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+2^{2n+1})}{(n+1)(1+2^n)}|x|<1.$$
The limit apparently goes to $0$ because the radius of convergence is $\infty$. Usually when I get limit that goes to $0$, it is a fraction where only the denominator contains $n$, and I know the limit goes to $1$ if the degree on the top is the same as the degree on the bottom. So I am unsure on how to evaluate this limit though.

Comment: You've made a mistake in your series, $e^{2x} = \sum \dfrac{2^n x^n}{n!}$ and with the ratio test there shouldn't be a $2n+1$ in the exponent of the 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^x+e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2x)^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n+(2x)^{n}}{n!}$$
I presume you used the ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\dfrac{\frac{x^{n+1}+2^{n+1}\cdot x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{x^n+2^n\cdot x^{n}}{n!}}\right\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\dfrac{x+2^{n+1}\cdot x}{(n+1)(1+2^n)}\right\vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1+2^{n}}{(n+1)(1+2^n)}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{2^n}}{\frac{1}{2^n}}\vert x\vert$$ $$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\to0}+1}{\underbrace{(n+1)}_{\to\infty}(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2^n}}_{\to0}+1)}\vert x\vert=0<1$$
So, for all $x$, we have convergence by the ratio test and $R=\infty$ as you said. Your only trouble was finding that limit.